# tomcat7 domain settings

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, tomcat7, ubuntu-server

I want to publish (in simple terms) different folders to different website domains. e.g *mysite2.com*, *mysite1.com*. In apache2 httpd, I have to bind. How exactly do I do that in Tomcat 7? I have also made some NetBeans projects (I guess I have to copy paste the war files somewhere)?

I have a VPS, I occasionally use FTP to upload files. So I want to put the WAR files to my /home folder so that it's easy for permissions. (I mean I want to change the default folder for website files)

I really don’t know :

1) where to make configs for multiple domains and their content paths?
   The default is

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps">
```

How to change that to /home/www/site1 /home/www/site2 and how to to do config for each  site domain?

2) what exactly should be written in server.xml (iirc) in the `<host>` tag and would there be any conflict with the Catalina home?

I am using Ubuntu 12.10. I do not have Apache httpd running. Only Tomcat is there.

I know this is a newbie question, but that’s what I am and I am unable to grasp things by Google or Tomcat 7 docs.

Very confused. Need your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 different questions here.

The first is how to deploy web applications in Tomcat. I recommend you read http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html . Once you configure the manager application, it's the easiest way to deploy an app for a beginner.

The second question you have is external access of you applications on different addresses. Apache covers that with VirtualServers. As, in any case, you [can't run tomcat on default port 80](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=run%20tomcat%20port%2080&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gl=uk), I suggest you use Apache VirtualServers and [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) to achieve that.

Comment: I have resolved the port 80 issue though. 2. I do not have apache httpd running. only tomcat is there. see the

updated: I really don’t know :